# Simulation about quantile regression

Tags: simulation, quantile-regression

This is what I have done in R:

```
> quantile<-rq(log(response)~gender+age+I(age^2)+gender*age+gender*I(age^2),data=Modified,
+ tau=0.9)
> summary(quantile)

Call: rq(formula = log(response) ~ gender + age + I(age^2) + gender * 
    age + gender * I(age^2), tau = 0.9, data = Modified)

tau: [1] 0.9

Coefficients:
                    Value    Std. Error t value  Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)          3.50682  0.04854   72.24571  0.00000
genderMale           0.05580  0.05556    1.00419  0.31534
age                 -0.02705  0.01197   -2.26063  0.02383
I(age^2)             0.00102  0.00066    1.56271  0.11819
genderMale:age      -0.02109  0.01426   -1.47927  0.13913
genderMale:I(age^2)  0.00230  0.00079    2.89264  0.00384
```

So now from the summary, we can get the estimated values for each variable, however we have no information about the distribution of the errors, so how could I simulate from this specific model. The behind reason for why I want to do it is that I want to test whether the results from the quantile regression is reliable at the extremes of the data range,

Comment: Can you say a little bit more about your question? What is it you want to know? What have you tried so far? etc. I'm not sure your question is answerable in its current form.

Comment: The fitted model does not contain enough information to simulate an entire distribution.  You might find it easier to simulate data from a known model, then fitting a quantile regression model to those data, repeatedly.

Comment: could you give me more details about your answers please@FrankHarrell Harrell

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simulate from quantile regression](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/65616/simulate-from-quantile-regression)