# Quantile regression - power analysis

Tags: r, simulation, statistical-power, quantile-regression

I need to put together a (likely simulation-based) power analysis of a quantile regression. The analysis should include changing effect size (increasing slope).

In `lm()` or `glm()` cases, I used the model's predictions and the variability of the residuals to simulate a response. I can't quite figure out how to do it in `rq()`.

There are a couple of questions out there trying to get at the same thing, but no answers... here are the links:
[How to calculate the power of my quantile regression model?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/221681/how-to-calculate-the-power-of-my-quantile-regression-model#)

[Simulation about quantile regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/65361/simulation-about-quantile-regression)

Here's a fake toy data set (already set for quantile reg analysis) and `lm()` example on trying to detect interaction between 2 predictor variables.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(quantreg)
library(plyr)
library(reshape2)

set.seed(1000)
df <- data.frame(x = 1:50, z = "a")
df$y <- 6 + 0.1*df$x + rnorm(50, mean = 0, sd = 0.1 + 0.05*df$x)

df1 <- data.frame(x = 1:50, z = "b")
df1$y <- 6 + 0.11*df1$x + rnorm(50, mean = 0, sd = 0.1 + 0.05*df1$x)

df <- rbind(df, df1)
ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + geom_point(aes(colour = z))

# fake lm approach; how to do the same with quantreg?

model <- lm(y ~ x*z, data=df)

dataLast <- df[df$z == "a",]
temp <- data.frame(Resids = resid(model), z = df$z)
SDs_full <- ddply(temp, .(z), summarize, SD = sd(Resids))

N <- nrow(df)
NLast <- nrow(dataLast)

out <- list()
k <- 1
EF <- seq(0, 10, 1) ## effect sizes
repetitions <- 10 

for (ef in EF){
out[[k]] <- matrix(nrow=repetitions, ncol=1)
```

simulate data, to look at power to detect the interaction between x and z

```
for(i in 1:repetitions){
    coef_ef <- as.numeric(coef(model)[2])*(100 + ef)/100

    means <- as.numeric(coef(model)[1]) + coef_ef*dataLast$x  

    responses <- rnorm(n = nrow(dataLast), mean = means, sd = SDs_full[SDs_full$z == "a",]$SD)    
    responses <- data.frame(responses = responses, z = "Comparison", x = dataLast$x)

    meansLast <- as.numeric(coef(model)[1]) +
        as.numeric(coef(model)[2])*log(dataLast$x)

    responsesLast <- rnorm(n = nrow(dataLast), mean = meansLast, sd = SDs_full[SDs_full$z == "a",]$SD)    
    responsesLast <- data.frame(responses = responsesLast, z = "a", x = dataLast$x)

    responses <- rbind(responses, responsesLast)
    responses$z <- factor(responses$z, levels = c("a", "Comparison"))

    model1 <- lm(responses ~ x*z, data = responses)
    model2 <- lm(responses ~ x + z, data = responses)
    temp <- anova(model1, model2, test = "F")
    p <- as.numeric(unlist(temp[6]))[2]
    out[[k]][i, 1] <- p
            } #i

out[[k]] <- as.data.frame(out[[k]])
out[[k]]$EF <- ef
k <- k + 1
       } #ef
```

now to plot the results (a plot that doesn't mean much, because power = 1)

```
out <- melt(out, id.vars = colnames(out[[1]]))
out <- subset(out, select = -c(L1))
out$V2 <- ifelse(out$V1 < 0.05, 1, 0)

try1 <- ddply(out, .(EF), summarize, Power = sum(V2), N = length(V2))
try1$Power <- try1$Power/try1$N

ggplot(try1) +
geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 0.8), linetype = "dashed", colour = "darkgrey")+
geom_line(aes(x = EF, y = Power))
```